# Integer validation - not re-displaying user input

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a domain class:

```
class Test {
    Integer blah
}
```

and a scafollded controller and views. Filling `blah` in the form with invalid `Integer` (`1a` or `ab`) fails validation but doesn't re-populate the text box with the invalid user input.

I think I understand why this happens (`blah` of the domain instance passed back to the gsp for rendering cannot hold alpha characters beacause it is an `Integer`), but is there a nice way of re-populating the form with invalid input?

There are a couple of solutions: have a transient `String blah` with a regex validator ensuring the input is numeric and then override the `Integer blah` getter to grab `String blah` value. Then show `String blah` on the form. Alternatively give everyone HTML5 compient browser where `type=number` works :)

Are there better ways of solving this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's an error creating or saving the domain object, couldn't you return the params object to the view, and repopulate the inputs from that if it exists?

Answer (score 0):

> I think I understand why this happens (blah of the domain instance passed back to the gsp for rendering cannot hold alpha characters beacause it is an Integer),

Correct, usually repopulating a form works like this

```
  class MyController {
    def showForm() {
      [bean: new Test()]
    }

    def processForm(Test bean) {
      if (!bean.validate()) {
        render view: 'showForm', model: [bean: bean] 
      } else {
        // save the bean or whatever....
      }
    }
  }
```

And the fields of the form in `showForm.gsp` are set using:

```
<g:textField name="blah" value="${bean.blah}"/>
```

Because `bean` cannot be returned to the form holding values of the wrong type, these values will be "lost" if you use the markup above. However, these values should still be available in the `params` object, so I guess the following should work (haven't tested it though)

```
<g:textField name="blah" value="${bean.blah ?: params.blah}"/>
```

It's possible to define a single template that defines the logic and style for each field - rather than repeating it for every field - using the new [fields](http://grails.org/plugin/fields) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The [`fieldValue`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/fieldValue.html) tag is designed for this use case:

> Inspects a bean which has been the subject of data binding and obtains the value of the field either from the originally submitted value in the bean's errors object populated during data binding or from the value of a bean's property. Once the value is obtained it will be automatically HTML-encoded.

For example:

```
<g:textField name="blah" value="${fieldValue(bean: testInstance, field: 'blah'}"/>
```